# Cognitive Services, Face API Microsoft

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, xamarin, azure

Estoy desarrollando una app android consumiendo servicios de la API Face de Microsoft. Me surge la duda de cómo obtener o ver dónde se guardan los grupos de personas y personas que hay en los diferentes grupos. O si alguien sabe si estos datos se pueden consultar desde algún apartado de Azure o cualquier otro sitio. Entiendo que si creo una lista y es guardada, debe de estar en algún sitio, pero no logro encontrar donde se ubican estos datos.

Comment: Yo tuve un problema similar hace unos días, en mi código no declaraba el lugar donde iban a ser almacenados, yo usé ésto https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/howtoidentifyfacesinimage Espero te sirva.

Comment: No entiendo los votos negativos, comprendo perfectamente la pregunta y es cierto que la documentación de la API en cuestión es algo confusa

Comment: Yo tampoco entiendo los votos negativos, y aún menos sin dejar ningún comentario del motivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La API de PersonGroup Create es un poco diferente en que la persona que llama especifica la ID. De todos modos, esta ID se almacena en el almacenamiento de los Servicios Cognitivos, junto con toda la información relacionada, como las personas que componen este grupo. La naturaleza exacta del almacenamiento es intencionalmente opaca.

Se puede enumerar los PersonGroup asociados con su clave API con List API. Se puede consultar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46856760/where-is-persongroup-saved-for-the-face-api-from-ms-cognitive-services